# Angular Template Literals : Addition after converting string to number becoming just concatenation

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I am working on a Billing Application based on Angular 4. I had to make a change in a logic that I've applied. But when I made the change, everything is broken. I inspected deep and find that the Addition after converting String to Integer inside templates becomes just concatenation.

That is in normal JavaScript,

```
100 + +"28"
```

will be `128`

```js
console.log(100 + +"28");
```

But in Angular template literals, it becomes `10028`

I tried in these 3 ways

```
{{100 + +"28"}}

{{100 + (+"28")}}

{{(100 + (+"28"))}}
```

But both 3 times, it produces 10028.

I can't store it in a variable and display because I am using `ngFor`.

The MCVE from my original code is

```
<div class="row bill-entry" data-id="" *ngFor="let i of item">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
    {{i.itemName}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2">
    {{i.qty}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="row price">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="over-price">{{ (((i.qty * i.ind_price) / (100 + (+i.gst))) * 100).toFixed(2) }}
                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  -> Problem
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [minimal plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/35Y0HZXSsvTxrUzrtgb7/) in which I reproduced this issue

---

Note:

GST is the Goods and Service Tax in India. The final price of a product is inclusive of GST. The client will enter the final price. The app should find it's price without GST and GST. That is if the price of a product is INR 100.00 and GST is 28%, then it's actual price is INR 78.13 and GST is INR 21.87. The client will enter just 100. I have to calculate the other 2 values and print it in Bill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can only assume...

`i.gst` is a string in your data, which means you will need an additional method on your controller / component to convert it into an integer or a float.

I have taken your plunker and added a data property and the respective method to convert it

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 *ngFor="let i of data">Hello {{100+getNumber(i.gst)}}</h2>
      <h2>Hello {{100+ (+"28")}}</h2>
      <h2>Hello {{(100+ (+"28"))}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;

  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

  // data array
  data = [
    {gst: "28"},
    {gst: "32"}
  ];

  // method to convert string to float
  getNumber(string) {
    return parseFloat(string);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thanks Dale, It's working. I already tried parseInt inline that is `{{parseInt(i.gst)}}` but it produced error _co.parseInt is not a function. But a dedicated function did the job. Thanks for the answer